# ESP32 writeStringEEPROM adds unwanted nembers when I use the letter '&'

Tags: arduino, esp32, eeprom

I am trying to use this code:
https://github.com/jatocode/WifiConnect/blob/master/WifiConnect/WifiConnect.ino with my ESP32.
The problem is that my wifi network name is "y&t" and when I am trying to use it the progrem saves to the EEPROM "y&26t" insted, with other networks names in my area it dosn't have a problem.

[image]
[image]

I will be greatful if somebady knows how to solve this problem.

Comment: the esp32 saves the ssid and password used in begin() to flash if WiFi.persistent is true (by default it is) and uses it at boot if WiFi.setAutoConnect is true (default too). so why store it in EEPROM? this sketch is for esp8266 but it should work for esp32 with small changes too https://github.com/jandrassy/lab/blob/master/ConfigurationAP/ConfigurationAP.ino

Comment: will it still save the credentials after OTA?
thanks for trying to help !

Comment: why not? OTA has nothing to do with it

Comment: I tried this program and i had the same result instead of y&t it gives y%26t :/

Comment: it is the URL encoding from browser. you must decode it. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Comment: thank you for helping me understand the problem. now I will look where I can find the code magic that will solve this.

Comment: @Juraj the code https://github.com/jandrassy/lab/blob/master/ConfigurationAP/ConfigurationAP.ino doesn't work after restarting, so it won't work if I will do  OTA.

Comment: try to add `WiFi.persistent(true); WiFi.setAutoConnect(true);` in `setup()`

Comment: I tried this didn't work:\ @Juraj

Comment: sorry. on esp32 they removed the autoconnect feature. use `WiFi.begin();` without parameters before `WiFi.waitForConnectResult();` in setup();

Comment: I updated my ConfigurationAP sketch on GitHub https://github.com/jandrassy/lab/blob/master/ConfigurationAP/ConfigurationAP.ino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Juraj I solved the problem.

I used in this code a decoder from here: https://circuits4you.com/2019/03/21/esp8266-url-encode-decode-example/

```cpp
/*
  Configuration AP example
  The example shows a very simple Configuration Access Point.
  created in August 2019
  by Juraj Andrassy https://github.com/jandrassy
*/
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiAP.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
// #include <String.h>

String urldecode(String str);
unsigned char h2int(char c);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);

  // WiFi.disconnect(); // forget the persistent connection to test the Configuration AP
  
  WiFi.persistent(true);

  // waiting for connection to remembered  Wifi network
  Serial.println("Waiting for connection to WiFi");
  WiFi.begin(); // use SSID and password stored by SDK
  WiFi.waitForConnectResult();

  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Could not connect to WiFi. Starting configuration AP...");
    configAP();
  } else {
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  }
}

void loop() {
}

void configAP() {

  WiFiServer configWebServer(80);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA); // starts the default AP (factory default or setup as persistent)

  Serial.print("Connect your computer to the WiFi network ");
  // Serial.print(WiFi.softAP());
  Serial.println();
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("and enter http://");
  Serial.print(ip);
  Serial.println(" in a Web browser");

  configWebServer.begin();

  while (true) {

    WiFiClient client = configWebServer.available();
    if (client) {
      char line[64];
      int l = client.readBytesUntil('\n', line, sizeof(line));
      line[l] = 0;
      client.find((char*) "\r\n\r\n");
      if (strncmp_P(line, PSTR("POST"), strlen("POST")) == 0) {
        l = client.readBytes(line, sizeof(line));
        line[l] = 0;

        // parse the parameters sent by the html form
        const char* delims = "=&";
        strtok(line, delims);
        const char* ssid = strtok(NULL, delims);
        strtok(NULL, delims);
        const char* pass = strtok(NULL, delims);
        
        // decoding the ssid and the password for ASCII characters
        String ssidS = String(ssid);
        String ssidSdecode= urldecode(ssidS);
        ssid=const_cast<char*>(ssidSdecode.c_str());
        String passS = String(pass);
        String passSdecode= urldecode(passS);
        pass=const_cast<char*>(passSdecode.c_str());
        
        // send a response before attemting to connect to the WiFi network
        // because it will reset the SoftAP and disconnect the client station
        client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"));
        client.println(F("Connection: close"));
        client.println(F("Refresh: 10")); // send a request after 10 seconds
        client.println();
        client.println(F("<html><body><h3>Configuration AP</h3><br>connecting...</body></html>"));
        client.stop();

        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
        Serial.println(ssid);
        WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
        WiFi.waitForConnectResult();

        // configuration continues with the next request

      } else {

        client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"));
        client.println(F("Connection: close"));
        client.println();
        client.println(F("<html><body><h3>Configuration AP</h3><br>"));

        int status = WiFi.status();
        if (status == WL_CONNECTED) {
          client.println(F("Connection successful. Ending AP."));
        } else {
          client.println(F("<form action='/' method='POST'>WiFi connection failed. Enter valid parameters, please.<br><br>"));
          client.println(F("SSID:<br><input type='text' name='i'><br>"));
          client.println(F("Password:<br><input type='password' name='p'><br><br>"));
          client.println(F("<input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>"));
        }
        client.println(F("</body></html>"));
        client.stop();

        if (status == WL_CONNECTED) {
          delay(1000); // to let the SDK finish the communication
          Serial.println("Connection successful. Ending AP.");
          configWebServer.stop();
          WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

String urldecode(String str) {
    String encodedString="";
    char c;
    char code0;
    char code1;
    for (int i =0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        c=str.charAt(i);
      if (c == '+') {
        encodedString+=' ';  
      } else if (c == '%') {
        i++;
        code0=str.charAt(i);
        i++;
        code1=str.charAt(i);
        c = (h2int(code0) << 4) | h2int(code1);
        encodedString+=c;
      } else {
        encodedString+=c;  
      }
      
      yield();
    }
  return encodedString;
}
 
unsigned char h2int(char c) {
    if (c >= '0' && c <='9') {
        return((unsigned char)c - '0');
    }
    
    if (c >= 'a' && c <='f') {
        return((unsigned char)c - 'a' + 10);
    }
    
    if (c >= 'A' && c <='F') {
        return((unsigned char)c - 'A' + 10);
    }
    return(0);
}
```